# Nested fields in django rest framework standard POST form

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have been reading about nested serializers and everything seemed to be good except for one thing.

https://blog.devgenius.io/nested-serializers-in-django-rest-framework-6b36bf011074

According to this article, when I opened the DRF page http://localhost:8000/api/v1/profile/, I found that the POST form did not include the Hobbies field. I understand that this is because of the nested serializer and DRF cannot render it as a field.

Previously, I have used SlugField to show related objects, but this time I want to take the opportunity to add new Hobbies along with the Profile in one form.

However, I think it might look strange if I want to add two new Hobbies with a new Profile. In that case, how should my form look like? Should it be a nested form with its own submit button? That doesn't seem RESTful.

Perhaps I should not use DRF forms in this case and use tools like Postman instead? With Postman, I can simply send the list of Hobbies with Profile data and they will be saved in the database, as shown in the guide above.

Thanks a lot for everyone!